# Regex not replacing all occurrences

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of a Regex search & replace using the following code and for some reason it only replaces the first occurrence:

```js
var userContent = '<div class="header"><!--Start Main Menu--><ul class="main-menu"> <li><a href="/">Home</a> </li> <li><a href="/">About</a> </li> <li><a href="/">Portfolio</a> </li> <li><a href="/">Contact</a> </li> </ul><!--End Main Menu--></div><div class="footer"><!--Start Main Menu--><ul class="main-menu"> <li><a href="/">Home</a> </li> <li><a href="/">About</a> </li> <li><a href="/">Portfolio</a> </li> <li><a href="/">Contact</a> </li> </ul><!--End Main Menu--></div>';

var menuItems = "<li><a href='/'>Home</a></li><li><a href='/about'>About</a></li><li><a href='/portfolio'>Portfolio</a></li><li><a href='/contact'>Contact</a></li>";

var quote = function(str) {
    return str.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]/(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
};

var re = new RegExp(quote('<!--Start Main Menu-->') + "[^]+" + quote('<!--End Main Menu-->'), 'g');
userContent = userContent.replace(re, '<!--Start Main Menu--><ul class="main-menu">' + menuItems + '</ul><!--End Main Menu-->');

console.log(userContent);
```

I can't seem to figure out why, I've stated in quote `/g` and I've tried adding `/g` to userContent.replace but it just doesn't seem to like it.

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/xqt3kj7r/

Comment: Parsing regex with HTML is not a good idea.

Comment: @NisargShah I know, but in this case it's the situation I'm working with. If it's parsing the HTML fine for one occurrence, why won't it do it for both? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can do it with Javascript by processing DOM elements. Can you explain what you are trying to do, in the question?

Comment: @NisargShah I'm basically trying to replace everything in between <!--Start Main Menu--> and <!--End Main Menu--> with the variable menuItems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are matching *greedy*, and so the regular expression ate up all the chars within the *first* occurrence of 'Start Main Menu' and the *last* occurrence of 'End Main Menu'.

What would be required is a *non-greedy* match. Try this:

```js
var userContent = '<div class="header"><!--Start Main Menu--><ul class="main-menu"> <li><a href="/">Home</a> </li> <li><a href="/">About</a> </li> <li><a href="/">Portfolio</a> </li> <li><a href="/">Contact</a> </li> </ul><!--End Main Menu--></div><div class="footer"><!--Start Main Menu--><ul class="main-menu"> <li><a href="/">Home</a> </li> <li><a href="/">About</a> </li> <li><a href="/">Portfolio</a> </li> <li><a href="/">Contact</a> </li> </ul><!--End Main Menu--></div>';

var menuItems = "<li><a href='/'>Home</a></li><li><a href='/about'>About</a></li><li><a href='/portfolio'>Portfolio</a></li><li><a href='/contact'>Contact</a></li>";

var quote = function(str) {
    return str.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]/(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
};

var re = new RegExp(quote('<!--Start Main Menu-->') + "[^]*?" + quote('<!--End Main Menu-->'), 'g');
userContent = userContent.replace(re, '<!--Start Main Menu--><ul class="main-menu">' + menuItems + '</ul><!--End Main Menu-->');

console.log(userContent);
```

Note how the RE changed from `+` to `*?`. I don't find it a good practice to approach this with a regular expression, but this is just to show you how it could have worked.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Just out of interest, what would be the better way to do this?

Comment: I'd go with Nisarg's proposal. Of course you'd need to adapt it to replace *all* occurrences of main menu, but that can be tackled I guess.

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in the comments, if you wish to process HTML for this, you can select the `.header` class, and replace it's `innerHTML` with the new HTML from variable `menuItems`.

In the snippet below, I have wrapped the variable `menuItems` in a `ul` tag to ensure that as we overwrite the original `ul` tag insider the `div.header`, the new `li` tags have a `ul` around them.

Also, I have modified one of the `li` in `menuItems` to show that the list is actually getting replaced.

```js
var userContent = '<div class="header"><!--Start Main Menu--><ul class="main-menu"> <li><a href="/">Home</a> </li> <li><a href="/">About</a> </li> <li><a href="/">Portfolio</a> </li> <li><a href="/">Contact</a> </li> </ul><!--End Main Menu--></div><div class="footer"><!--Start Main Menu--><ul class="main-menu"> <li><a href="/">Home</a> </li> <li><a href="/">About</a> </li> <li><a href="/">Portfolio</a> </li> <li><a href="/">Contact</a> </li> </ul><!--End Main Menu--></div>';

var menuItems = "<ul><li><a href='/'>Home</a></li><li><a href='/about'>About</a></li><li><a href='/portfolio'>Portfolio</a></li><li><a href='/contact'>Contact (new item)</a></li></ul>";

var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("placeholder");

// Add the HTML to the placeholder Div.
placeholderDiv.innerHTML = userContent;

setTimeout(function() {
  // Now we need to replace the content inside the header element.
  // Select the children of #placeholder that have class "header"
  var headerElements = document.querySelectorAll("#placeholder div.header");

  if (headerElements.length > 0) {
    console.log("Replacing innerHTML");
    var header = headerElements[0];
    header.innerHTML = menuItems;
  }

}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```